# Unable to send values from Angular to database. Getting 204 status code in network headers

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am unable to debug what the error is here. Why is it showing me successful when I am getting the response as true and unable to push values to the DB. I am unable to debug what the error is. Someone,please help me out
[image: This is in my services]

[image: This is in .ts file]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more information? The API and all. Seems like the data getting passed is the same (to request payload), that is why its returning status 204 i.e the content didn't changed.

Comment: I had added some more data. Unfortunately, I cannot add the complete code due to some restrictions. Hope this helps thanks

Comment: The second screenshot shows the request method for Options. You'll need to look at the one for Post. If you run the API through Postman does it work? This should determine if the bug is Angular or .NET!

Comment: Yes @Greg it does work in postman with no issues at all

Comment: What do you think is wrong

Comment: It looks like the issue is not with .NET. You're going to need to compare what the website is posting with Postman script. Can you replace screenshot 2 with the Request Method: POST (at the moment it's showing OPTIONS)

Comment: Also can you add code as HTML block instead of screenshot. It's easier to read & re-create the issue. The reason why you see the alert 'User registered successfully!' is because there is a single equals, when it should be triple equal for if(this.Status = true). This is suppressing your error message

Comment: Thank you so much @Greg. It was such a silly mistake. I got the desired output after comparing the two of them. But the triple equal gives unsuccessful alert even after the data is being reflected in the database

Comment: Check your postman script to see what the responses is. It may be the response data is not Boolean e.g 'true'. You can also check this on you Chrome Dev tools